# Automatically sort list messages to list folder with IMAP

Tags: imap, mutt

I would like to automatically move received messages to list-specific folders on an IMAP server with mutt. All these lists are `lists` known to mutt.

What I do right now is periodically tag messages by `Sender` and then `tag-save` them to the right folder. Mutt already suggests the correct folder. This seems way too pedestrian to me, and I feel there should be some way to automate this.

I know there are specific tools available to do this outside of a MUA, but the only ways to access this server seems to be trough some MUA (e.g. I don't have shell access).

How would I best do this inside mutt?

Comment: The claws-mail MUA can do that easily, but that's a GUI app.

Answer (score 5):

`mutt` is an interactive MUA, without automatic filtering capabilities. Your best choice would be to find (or write) a scriptable IMAP client.

Sometimes mail servers also have a web interface with filter editing features, or the ManageSieve protocol.

---

Or, very ugly but doable:

- grab messages to your own computer using fetchmail/getmail/offlineimap
- filter through procmail/maildrop/sieve
- store on your own IMAP server, *or* upload back using offlineimap.

Comment: +1 for mentioning to check any available web interfaces.  server side IMAP filtering >> client-side IMAP filtering

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but I have to say it doesn't help me at all. If anything I will end up writing a keyboard macro to do this in mutt.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [imapfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) to do just that.  From the documentation:

> IMAPFilter is a mail filtering utility. It connects to remote mail
>   servers using the Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP), sends
>   searching queries to the server and processes mailboxes based on the
>   results. It can be used to delete, copy, move, flag, etc. messages
>   residing in mailboxes at the same or different mail servers. The 4rev1
>   and 4 versions of the IMAP protocol are supported.
>
> IMAPFilter uses the Lua programming language as a configuration and
>   extension language.